# Vertices Tangled in UV unwrapping

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am following a tutorial by Blender Guru:

[Blender Beginner UV Unwrapping Tutorial (Chair Part 7) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo)

I'm on the UV wrapping episode and every time I unwrap this happens:

[image: tangled UVs]

It is supposed to look like this in the tutorial

[image: reference UVs]

I have applied scale rotation and location and this still happens,

Here is a photo of the object with seams and creases

[image: model]

I don't want to use Smart UV Project because I still want to follow the tutorial.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Have you marked a seam along the length of the object?

Comment: Also see the first comment under the video. I don't think that option in the modifier was available when Andrew did that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, its was fixed when i added seams along the edges!